# Why added predictors improved performance in decision trees if they don't appear in the model?

Tags: cart, predictor, model-evaluation

although I've been working some months now with decision trees, I still have issues understanding some things and also finding a right source to answer my questions. Maybe I'm not using the right terminology. If so, I would appreciate if someone points me in the right direction regarding this question.

I am studying the effect of adding predictors to a decision tree (I'm using C50 but not particular reason why). So, when measuring the performance (accuracy, sensitivity, etc.) in a testing dataset (I used a training dataset for building the model), I observe that there is a point when the accuracy changes to a high value. When I look, which predictor I have added at that stage and I look the model resulting in that stage, I can see that although adding the new predictor has caused an increase in the accuracy, the model does not contain that predictor. It is indeed a different model from the previous step but doesn't contain the new predictor. So, what just happened? Is it something to do with the process of selecting the predictor in the split within the decision tree algorithm? 
Can anyone provide a good source of literature that could explain this?

Thank you!

### Edit

After the comments, I will try to explain the steps of my approach to see if someone can provide a good source for information or some explanation. I cannot put the actual model, since it's confidential stuff and I believe that it's something related with the randomness that Ben Kuhn indicates so a reproducible example might not be possible.
I use RStudio and C5.0 from the library(C50). I have good a dataframe with class and then columns with each of the predictors ordered in the way that I want them to be introduced in the model. I split the data in training and testing and use the training for the model.

Step 1: I take the class-column and the first column (predictor-1 column) and get model-1 with formula=CLASS ~ predictor-1.

Step 2: I evaluate the performance using the class column and predictor-1 column of the testing dataset.

Step 3: I add the predictor-2 column to training dataset and I get the model-2 with formula=CLASS ~ predictor-1 + predictor-2

Step 4: I evaluate the performance using testing dataset with class column, predictor-1 column and predictor-2 column

And this goes on with each of the predictors...

So, the question arises when I added one predictor, the resulted model changed improving the performance but did not include the new predictor. So if that is due to some randomness since I have changed the training dataset, where is that effect exactly in the construction of the classifier? I didn't change the number of samples, that remains the same, I only change the columns added, so I don't understand it...

Cheers

Comment: Hello - i think to get a good answer you would need to include output that gives evidence of the problem, and perhaps the code used to obtain that output.  But then maybe this is more of a software question, one that would be best listed on the applicable software's listserv or what-have-you.

Comment: This may just be due to randomness in the model-fitting process. If you run your experiment again with a different random seed, do you observe the same effect?

Comment: Thanks for the comments. Rolando2, unfortunately I don't think I can put the actual model/output here since it's kind of confidential and with another example this might not occur, maybe due to the randomness as Ben Kuhn indicates. Regarding to the software, I'm using Rstudio and C5.0 as classifier from library(C50). @Ben Kuhn, I have repeated my experiment with a different random seed and I get the same result. I think this is a more theoretical question rather than a software one. Maybe the added predictor, modifies someway the selection process in each split, but I don't understand how?

Comment: @BenKuhn, I misunderstood how C5.0 works with the seed when I commented earlier. When I gave a closer look to the documentation, the seed affects in the selection of the sample of the training dataset for the model. Since I was using 100% of the training, I always obtained the same model. When I chose for instance 80% of the training and varied the seed, I started getting different models. So I guess it's due to the randomness as you said since I do vary the dataset from one step to another in my code, maybe it's not the right approach...

Comment: What parameters are you supplying to the C50 algorithm (other than the features and data)?

Comment: @BenKuhn I'm just leaving it with the default parameters: model <- C5.0(formula, data). I think I've found if not the answer, the way to get there. I think it's something to do with the partitions/subsets of data in each node. Since I have more predictors in each step, the partitions of the data will be different and that may affect the way the tree selects the predictor for the split. This is still quite rough for me to understand but working on it with some reading: Quinlan 1986 [http://hunch.net/~coms-4771/quinlan.pdf] and [https://shapeofdata.wordpress.com/2013/07/02/decision-trees/].

Comment: @FabiolaFernández: as far as I understand it, the partition that the tree decides on should be determined solely by the feature it is splitting on. So if it never decides to split on the new feature, then it should learn the same splits as the other tree. Another potential explanation is that the second tree *is* splitting on the new feature, but those splits are getting pruned away from the final model. Can you see what models are learned if you disable pruning?

Comment: @BenKuhn, thank you for the comments and apologies for taking so long to reply (I was caught with some other work for weeks...). Following your advice, I forced "noGlobalpruning"=TRUE in the C.50 package and it seems that it shows now the new added predictors. However, the trees seems to be still slightly different from the previous. I still keep investigating about it but I think your comment above is the best explanation so far. Thanks a lot!

Comment: "it seems that it shows now the new added predictors"--you mean, in the trees that were different before, they *do* contain the new predictor that was added at that step? If so, isn't this the expected behavior (that the tree changed because it split on a newly-added predictor instead of a previous one)?

Comment: @BenKuhn, yes, you're right, it's the expected behavior. I guess I just didn't think my comment all the way through!I meant previous predictors are not in the tree anymore, but if the added one is better, it makes sense they're not in the new tree. Some of them still appear though, but I guess the new predictor just added a better combination with some of others to create a better tree, right?